# How many ways to arrange 4 xs, 6 ys in 10 spots?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to know how many ways I can arrange 4 xs and 6 ys in 10 spots in order to know how many products of 4 xs and 6 ys are equal to x<sup>4</sup>y<sup>6</sup>. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: have a look at [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: Hint: We need to **choose** the $4$ spots where x's will go.

Comment: Is it really as simple as 10 C 4?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Or the six spots where the y's will go :P

Comment: @Demi: Yes, it is that simple.

Comment: All products of 4 x's and 6 y's equal $x^4 y^6$.

Are you simply looking for the unique combinations of 4 x's and 6 y's?

Comment: @Demi  Affirmative.

Comment: @Gummybears: Poor $y$, condemned forever to play second fiddle to $x$.

Comment: You can also just think of it as the coefficient of $x^4y^6$ in $(x+y)^{10}$, since that is what you get when you expand out $(x+y)(x+y)\cdots(x+y)$ - each occurrence of $x^4y^{10}$ in that expansion is a way to order four $x$s and 6 $y$s.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Quite a tragic math story, isn't it?

Comment: There is a funny little essy by Stephen Leacock, *A, B, and C*, in *Sunshine Sketches of a Little Town*. Leacock does a character analysis of A, B, and C based on their roles in algebra "word problems." The energetic one is A, who digs ditches twice as fast as B, and three times as fast as poor C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $10!$ ways of arranging $10$ objects, so for example:

$$xyyxxyyyxy$$

Each example word has $4$ $x$'s, and although they are unlabelled, the same permutation appears $4!$ times. The same for the $6$ $y$'s, and so we need to divide by these, giving:

$$\dfrac{10!}{4!6!}$$

which is also written as:

$$\dbinom{10}{4} \;\text{or}\; \dbinom{10}{6}$$